# DNS rewrite link directory, alternative to dnslink

Tags: domain-name-system

a problem... I must configure DNS to handle a directory default in url.

what i see | *what it is*

example.tk | *example.tk/**a***

i can do that f.e. with **dnslink=/a/example.html**
but i cannot do that for a directory. i must do this without any firewall or redirections in main machine, just in dns settings in my domain.

what types can i use: **A, AAAA, CNAME, LOC, MX, NAPTR, RP, TXT**

Answer (score 1):

DNS knows nothing about anything but the host name. To do what you want, you'll need to modify your webserver configuration.

Comment: so why an TXT type setting with dnslink=/dir/to/file works?

Comment: That is something specific that works only with their service.